# Batch rename multiple bookmarks in Word .docx file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, openoffice, docx

Is it possible to rename multiple bookmarks in standard Word 97-2003 doc file?  I just finished a 400 page document, in Word 2010, with several hundred bookmarks that must be renamed and I definitely don't want to go in and rename them manually.  I found [this](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Bookmark_Tool.htm) Word add-in for enhancing the built-in Word Bookmark Dialog, but can't seem to get it to load properly into my document, if I can get it working it will solve my problem.  Until then are there any other straightforward methods for accomplishing this?  Maybe this can be accomplished using macros.  Right now I'm looking to see if OpenOffice supports batch renaming of bookmarks in a docx file.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a VBA macro in Word. The below macro, which is taken from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1583985) (and discussed in greater detail on the Web page), will prepend "NEW_" to each existing bookmark name, but it can be adapted to rename the bookmarks with whatever conventions are desired.

```
Sub RenameBookmarks()
'  although it does NOT rename them
'  it creates a new one for the same range
'  then deletes the old one

Dim BM_Names()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .Bookmarks.Count
    ReDim Preserve BM_Names(i)
    BM_Names(i) = .Bookmarks(i).Name
  Next
  For i = 1 To .Bookmarks.Count
    With .Bookmarks(BM_Names(i))
      .Range.Bookmarks.Add Name:="NEW_" & .Name, Range:=.Range
      .Delete
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

joeschwa's answer above is fine, but I'd like to extend it a bit, *for a good reason.*
Because it appears that you can't edit bookmark names directly, you have to, as joeschwa did, add new names and then delete the original bookmarks.
**The thing is, this creates an undesired side effect: all the existing references to the original bookmarks in the document will be broken!**

To overcome this, the references must be be redirected to the new bookmark names. My code below takes care of this. It does 3 things:

1. It first creates new bookmark names, as desired, and deletes the old ones - in a similar manner to joeschwa's code.

(note the comments in the code though. I offer a way to do this in a selection rather than in the entire doc; also, I offer a way there to deal with groups of bookmarks that are characterized by different prefixes. For instance, if you want to change all the bookmarks whose name starts with a "C1_" prefix, to, say, a "CH1_" prefix, you can do so, without affecting other bookmarks).

2. It redirects all references to the newly-renamed bookmarks in the main body of the doc.
3. It redirects all references to the newly-renamed bookmarks in all headers and footers of all types (on first pages of sections, on other pages of sections, etc.), on all sections of the doc.

```
' By Yiftach, 2018-4-9
'   There's no option in word to rename bookmarks, so this: _
    1.  creates a new one for the same range, then deletes the old one, and _
    2.  Fixes all existing cross-references in the doc, so that any references to old bookmarks are _
        re-routed to the respective new bookmarks which replaced them
          
'   This is especially useful for BULK/BATCH renaming. This assumes there's a pattern in bookmark names. _
    I.e. that a certain substring in a group of bookmarks is replaced by another substring. _
    e.g. if all bookmarks in chapter 1 start with "C1_", and I'm switching chapter order and want to _
    rename them "C2_". (But of course it can be used to replace a single bookmark as well).
    
'NOTE: Currently the old and new texts are hard coded as CONSTs at the top of the code. Adapt as needed.

'*****************EXTREME WARNING: Bookmark names must not contain the string "REF" ***********************
'*
'*        (in whatever case)!!! because of how i fix references to renamed bookmarks.
'*                  THIS CAN FUCK UP ALL REFERENCES IN THE DOC, IRREVERSABLY!
'*
'************************************************************************************************

Const old_txt_in_bookmark_names As String = "C1_"   'change as needed
Const new_txt_in_bookmark_names As String = "C2_"   'change as needed

'PART 1: RENAME BOOKMARKS (creates new bookmarks and deletes old)
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    
    For Each bm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks 'activedocument.bookmarks can be replaced with selection.bookmarks as needed
        If InStr(1, bm.Name, old_txt_in_bookmark_names, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'if you want to replace ALL bookmark names in the doc/selection _
                                                                                regardless of their prefix, remove the if statement and just _
                                                                                leave the next line
            bm.Range.Bookmarks.Add Name:=Replace(bm.Name, old_txt_in_bookmark_names, new_txt_in_bookmark_names), Range:=bm.Range
            bm.Delete
        End If
    Next bm

'PART 2: edit referenecs to the bookmarks that were renamed
'   2.1 In the main body of the doc (this doesn't treat headers and footers) _
'       (   even if in PART1 I choose to only rename bookmarks in the selection rather than in the entire doc _
            I still want to ensure that all cross-references in the doc are pointing to the renamed bookmarks correctly!)

    Dim doc As Word.Document
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    If doc.Fields.count >= 1 Then
            For i = 1 To doc.Fields.count
                fieldStr = doc.Fields(i).Code.Text
                If Left(fieldStr, 4) = " REF" Then
                    doc.Fields(i).Code.Text = Replace(fieldStr, old_txt_in_bookmark_names, new_txt_in_bookmark_names, , 1, vbTextCompare)
                    doc.Fields(i).Update
                End If
            Next i
    End If

'   2.2 In the doc headers and footers, in all doc sections

    For s = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.count
        For HFT = 1 To 3    'HFT stands for Header-Footer type, according to the WdHeaderFooterIndex Enumeration
                            '  Name                  Value Description
                            '  wdHeaderFooterEvenPages 3   Returns all headers or footers on even-numbered pages.
                            '  wdHeaderFooterFirstPage 2   Returns the first header or footer in a document or section.
                            '  wdHeaderFooterPrimary   1   Returns the header or footer on all pages other than the first page of a document or section.
    
        '   2.2.1   Treating references in HEADERS
            If doc.Sections(s).Headers(HFT).Range.Fields.count >= 1 Then
                For i = 1 To doc.Sections(s).Headers(HFT).Range.Fields.count
                    fieldStr = doc.Sections(s).Headers(HFT).Range.Fields(i).Code.Text
                    If Left(fieldStr, 4) = " REF" Then
                        doc.Sections(s).Headers(HFT).Range.Fields(i).Code.Text = Replace(fieldStr, old_txt_in_bookmark_names, new_txt_in_bookmark_names, , 1, vbTextCompare)
                        doc.Sections(s).Headers(HFT).Range.Fields.Update
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        '   2.2.2   Treating references in FOOTERS
            If doc.Sections(s).Footers(HFT).Range.Fields.count >= 1 Then
                For i = 1 To doc.Sections(s).Footers(HFT).Range.Fields.count
                    fieldStr = doc.Sections(s).Footers(HFT).Range.Fields(i).Code.Text
                    If Left(fieldStr, 4) = " REF" Then
                        doc.Sections(s).Footers(HFT).Range.Fields(i).Code.Text = Replace(fieldStr, old_txt_in_bookmark_names, new_txt_in_bookmark_names, , 1, vbTextCompare)
                        doc.Sections(s).Footers(HFT).Range.Fields.Update
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next HFT
    Next s
End Sub
```